# I want to Search a file for a String in Java

Tags: java, search

I am trying to create this self project and got stuck. I am trying to get a user input, search a  string [ ] with keywords for that input. If a keyword is found search the file for the sentence with the found keyword and return the entire sentence which includes the keyword. Should this be done in a for loop?

```
  public static void parseFile( Scanner searchStr ) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File("data.txt");
        String [] keywords = {" day","What church"," name","Leman", "Secular",   "bugs"};

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    while( searchStr.hasNext() )
    {

        String line = searchStr.nextLine().toLowerCase().toString();
        final String lineFromFile = scan.nextLine();
        for( String keyword : keywords )
        {
            if( lineFromFile.contains( keyword ) )
            {
                System.out.println( keyword );
            }
        }

    scan.close();
    //searchStr.close();

    }
}
```

And here is where i call the parseFile () but for some reason it does not search the file

```
                    parseFile(currentkeyword);
```

And let's say i have this text file called "data.txt"
which has a few elements.
      1. Bugs is a funny guy
      2. His name is written all over the wall

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have your `while(searchStr.hasNext)` if you want to search the file you should be looping on the file scanner ie. `while(scan.hasNext())`...I'm not sure what your other scanner is searchStr is it the user input because i would just store that in a string and pass the string to your `parseFile` method not the scanner...

Comment: So it would be best to store the entire input then pass it into a string? Then search the string for a keyword and then search the file? I was trying to search the input for a keyword and then search the file simultaneously but that's not possible from the feedback I am getting.

Comment: It would be best to use the scanner that has the file you are trying to search through and not a scanner that has no inputs.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do what is the user input from the keyboard?

Comment: I am trying to search a file for keywords. But upon user input I want to search the input string to see if it matches any of the keywords in my string array. If a keyword is found then i am trying to search the file with the found keyword and finally output the sentence which has the matching keyword.

Comment: You should pass in a string containing user input.  Then search the user input first to see if it contains a keyword.  You can loop on the keywords and use `userinput.contains(keyword)` if it contains the keyword then save it to search the file.  Then loop on the file scanner and search for the keywords found above...You also might need regex to decide what is a "sentence" and what isn't...

Comment: okay so newbie here right,  this is my code in main where i take user input and based on that input i call the parse file method, is it possible to assign "current line" which is my scanner to a string?                                                 while (!endloop) {
   System.out.print(" - ");
   currentline = new Scanner(darkly.nextLine().toLowerCase());
   if (currentline.findInLine("bye") == null) {

    
    parseFile();

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
while( searchStr.hasNext() )
```

Using two different scanners. Looks like `searchStr` is never fed a file to look through so this never goes through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to make all the keywords lowercase:

`String [] keywords = {" day","what church"," name","leman", "secular",   "bugs"};`

Also, you are using the wrong scanner.

`searchStr = new Scanner(file);`